# How to parse namp output xml file?

Tags: xml, parsing, awk

I have a scan results of some 50 vlans it was easy when i was scanning whole subnets with single nmap command but when it came to parsing / filtering assets information (e.g hostname , ip address) it become one big problem. Right now i have to open each xml file (using xml software) and locate individual tags and extract desired field.

Is it possible to extract desired fields using `awk / grep` etc?

Here is how the `xml` file look like

```
<address addr="192.168.1.1" addrtype="ipv4" />
<hostnames><hostname name="test@myserver.com" type="PTR" /></hostnames>
```

I'm only interested in `address addr` and `hostname name`

Here is the [xml file](http://www.speedyshare.com/files/30945772/5.xml).

WoW chris you did it for me it works perfectly now:D thanks to you. DO you know if this command would still work if the tag are on separate lines (not ended on same line as it started)

```
<address addr="192.168.1.1" addrtype="ipv4" />
<hostnames><hostname name="test@myserver.com" type="PTR" />
</hostnames>
```

I agree but i cannot understand your description of delimator -F"\"". The delimator \" is not located inside the xml file. I'm missing something

Sorry but i'm not understanding this what is '\' this for. Does it mean starting quotation mark ". Thankss

Thank you chris for being so helpful and that too in a very quick and easy way. How can i accept your answer now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated answer: Yes, a long as the part inside the quotation marks is not split across line, the code below will work.

A bit of explanation:
Awk splits its input into fiels. <-F"\""> tells awk to split the input string on double quotes. Each splited field in the input string is then assigned to a variable $1 .. $NF where NF stands for the number of fields. In your case you interested in the first after a double quote, which is the second field $2.

try:

$ cat file

```
<address addr="192.168.1.1" addrtype="ipv4" />
<hostnames><hostname name="test@myserver.com" type="PTR" /></hostnames>
```

Command:

```
awk -F"\"" '/<address|<hostnames/{print $2}' file
```

Output:

```
192.168.1.1
test@myserver.com
```

HTH Chris

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F '="|"' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++){ if($i~" addr$" && i+1<=NF)print $(i+1); if($i~"hostname name")print $(i+1)} }' yourXml
```

this should work if `addr="192.168.1.1"` or `name="test@myserver.com"`  was not broken by linebreak. the both can be in same line too.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to manipulate *xml* often, you could install *[XML Gawk](http://home.vrweb.de/~juergen.kahrs/gawk/XML/)*:

```
xgawk -lxml 'XMLSTARTELEM == "address" {
  print XMLATTR["addr"]
  }
XMLSTARTELEM == "hostname" {
  print XMLATTR["name"]
  }' infile
```

You'll need to remove the empty line(s) at the beginning of your *XML*
in order to process the file correctly.

Comment: Thank you dimitre i never knew that there was a separate utility for awk/xml thing. The syntax looks lot easier to understand too.